# Interconectar un IFRAME con una web PADRE

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap, iframe

me ocupa o siguiente:

Parto del siguiente codigo:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="data">
    <a href="#" >Opcion 1</a><br>
    <a href="#" >Opcion 2</a><br>
    <a href="#" >Opcion 3</a><br>
    </div>

    <div id="data2">
       <input type="text" size="20">
    </div>
    
     <script>

    $("a").click(function () {

      a = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

      var index = $("a").index(this);
      jQuery("#data2 input").val(a[index].innerHTML);
    });


    </script>
```

Asi como esta al dar click a un link el contenido de dicho link se copia en el input dentro del  hasta aqui todo perfecto.

**LO QUE QUIERO HACER**

Tengo una web padre.php que tiene un modal, en dicho modal hay un formulario que posee 2 input y un boton que abre un segundo modal que contiene el iframe descrito anteriormente iframe.php que contiene una lista de link y me gustaria orientacion para que.

1. Al dar click en alguno de los link del modal que contiene el iframe se copie el contenido del link en el input del formulario del primer modal y a su vez se cierre el modal que contiene el iframe.
2. No he logrado comprender como lograr conectar el iframe con la web padre, ya que en el IFRAME estan la lista de link y al dar click quiero que el contenido se copie en un input que esta en la web padre..!

Answer (score 1):

Si controlas ambos dominios deberías usar `window.postMessage()` y `window.addEventListener("message", callback)` para enviar, recibir y responder mensages entre padre e iframe. La documentación con ejemplos de MDN está [aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage), lamentablemente no está en español, pero los [ejemplos](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage#Example) se entienden.

Comment: Si en efecto si controlo ambos dominios de hecho el iframe esta dentro del mismo dominio, lo que pasa que es una extensión del código como un extra y ya esta hecho en el iframe y no quisiera modificar todo el código existente si no mas bien implementarlo. Voy a revisar la documentación suministrada a ver que tal..! Gracias

Comment: He intentado con la web sugerida y tambien he ingresado [http://www.cristalab.com/tutoriales/introduccion-a-html5-web-messaging-c105028l/](AQUI) sin exito..!